# ArcGIS for Developers Free Development and Testing Account suspended/expired?

Tags: arcgis-online, license, story-map

I signed up for an ArcGIS for Developers **[Free Development and Testing Account](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/sign-up/)** and when I signed into it today, it said it was suspended and or expired.

I thought the account was free for life.

Do I need to purchase a subscription like you need to do with the 30 day free trial account?

I have a story map that I need access to.

Is there any way to get my story map transferred to another account?

Comment: Sounds like you used up your 'free' 50 credits - The word "Introductory"  is used when signing up is $20 per month after that - contact ESRI http://www.esri.com/about-esri/contact they will provide more details on your account.

Comment: Not sure if your story map is shared publicly but if it is you can log in/create a free AGO account and find the story map and save a copy to the free account. http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/faq.htm#anchor5

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have exceeded your [50 credits](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/sign-up/).

I don't think it's [entirely free](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/03/25/arcgis-online-and-arcgis-for-developers-subscriptions/) but based on your usage and then you must buy a subscription.

You should try posting this on the ESRI forums or contacting a rep as they can give you more insight about your account. Here we can only speculate.

Answer (score 1):

You get 50 credits every month with the free developer account.  You can upgrade to a [paid developer plan](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/plans/) if you need more credits.

Unless you are pushing large datasets up there or playing with the routing, geoenriching, analysis and batch geocoding, it is actually quite an ample amount for doing story maps.

I have a fair few services and apps [on mine](http://simonjacksongis.maps.arcgis.com/) and I use around 20-30 depending on what i have been playing with. And although I work for a distributor, this is the same free plan that everyone else has.

And if you cannot wait till the end of the month, use the [ArcGIS Online Assistant](https://ago-assistant.esri.com/) to copy the content from one account to another one.

Answer (score 0):

The free developer account is for free and for life yes, but I have heard today that if you don't use it they suspend it.

They should have sent you an email or something to let you know about that.